# How to list my results in a for loop

Tags: grails

If i have this snippet from my action

```
for (c in AuthorList){
    def bookCount = Book.countByName(c)
}
```

How do i make my `bookCount` into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop is not required at all. ;)

```
authorList.collect { Book.countByName( it ) }
```

should give the list you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use <<

```
def list = []

for (c in AuthorList){
    def bookCount = Book.countByName(c)
    list << bookCount
}
```